# how to get the content of element on the other site - PHP

Tags: php, dom, element

I found a script that gives me the text inside an element from another site. But it requires a class element, and that element has no class.

**Is it possible for parents to select the child element?**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;

$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

// Most HTML Developers are chimps and produce invalid markup...
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->recover = true;

$doc->loadHTMLFile($rss_split[0]);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

$query = "//p[@class='ac']"; /* <----------------- this ------> */

$entries = $xpath->query($query);
echo ($entries->item(0)->textContent)."<br>";
```

Comment: What is the structure of the DOM you are trying to query? Not the entire thing but the bit you're querying.